# how to get array of coordinate from a polygon geometry

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis

Is there any spatial function in postgis that returns an array of cooordinates? i have a polygon as a geometry and i would like to have the longitude and latitude coordinates separated each in a separate array.
is it possible?

Comment: `ST_DumpPoints` expects a geometry, not a wkt literal, so using `ST_AsText` in the parameter has no use.

Comment: You cannot update your question with the answer I already gave to you. **query 2** is exactly my answer, even with the comments

Comment: @JimJones i will remove it

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of such function, but you can easily achieve it by dumping the points of your polygon with `ST_DumpPoints`, extracting the x and y coordinates with `ST_X` and `ST_Y`, and aggregate them with `array_agg`:

```
SELECT array_agg(ST_X(geom)),array_agg(ST_Y(geom))
FROM ST_DumpPoints('POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))');

    array_agg     |    array_agg     
------------------+------------------
 {30,40,20,10,30} | {10,40,40,20,10}
(1 row)
```

Keep in mind that `array_agg` relies on a `GROUP BY`, otherwise you'll aggregate all rows of your table, e.g. aggregating by id:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int, geom geometry(polygon));
INSERT INTO t VALUES 
(1,'POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))'),
(2,'POLYGON ((40 20, 50 50, 30 50, 20 30, 40 20))');

SELECT id, array_agg(ST_X((point).geom)),array_agg(ST_Y((point).geom))
FROM (
    SELECT id,ST_DumpPoints(geom) FROM t -- your big query goes here
  ) j (id,point)
GROUP BY id;

 id |    array_agg     |    array_agg     
----+------------------+------------------
  2 | {40,50,30,20,40} | {20,50,50,30,20}
  1 | {30,40,20,10,30} | {10,40,40,20,10}
(2 rows)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c8d4ab6c698799fd0b1005d7b66da075)

Comment: please have a look at the update section posted above

Comment: i am trying to integrate the code you posted in the big query i have the one you showed in the chat session

Comment: @LetsamrIt just apply the logic I used above. If you don't manage, create a fiddle with sample data using create table and insert statements. finally, post your expected results (in a table format)

Comment: thanks, but please i am trying to integrate the code you posted into the main query i have the one you saw in the chat session but i receive syntax error at SELELCT

Comment: @LetsamrIt what does the error say? Post the error and create a fiddle with sample data using create table and insert statements. finally, post your expected results (in a table format)

Comment: can we please continue in a chat session. because i cant post the entire query here

Comment: @LetsamrIt: this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i added update section above. please have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233117/discussion-between-jim-jones-and-letsamrit).